# AutoHotKey Error "variable name contains an illegal character "100.000000"

Tags: autohotkey

I am making an AutoHotKey script so that I have media keys on my media key-less keyboard.
All of the shortcuts are working but i want to make one that will set the volume to max, unless it is already, in which case it would set it to 10. 
Here is my script as it is:

```
    SoundGet, master_volume

    ^!Down::SendInput {Media_Play_Pause}
    ^!Left::SendInput {Media_Prev}
    ^!Right::SendInput {Media_Next}
    ^!Up::SendInput {Media_Stop}
    ^!+Down::SendInput {Volume_Mute}
    ^!+Left::SendInput {Volume_Down}
    ^!+Right::SendInput {Volume_Up}
    ^!+Up::if (%master_volume% = 100) {
            SoundSet, 10
        } else {
            SoundSet, 100
        }
```

But I keep getting the error "Error: The following variable name contains an illegal character: "100.000000"" (the 100.000000 is what my volume is set to, e.g. if it's set to half maximum, it'll read 50.000000) and it highlights "if (%master_volume% = 100)" line ... 
I'm pretty new to AutoHotKey, but I have read through a lot of (what I thought were) relevant docs and can't figure it out

Comment: this is a syntax issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

> ^!+Up::
>   if (master_volume = 100) {
>       SoundSet, 10
>   } else {
>       SoundSet, 100
>   }
>   return

remove %'s around "master_volume"

Answer (score 3):

The error comes from you using the `%master_volume% the way you are.  Consider:

When you do this:

```
somevariable = george
```

the value of `somevariable` is set to "george"

But when you do this:

```
%somevariable% = george
```

the variable name is set to "george"

That means when you do this:

```
%master_volume% = 100
```

You are taking the *value* of `variable_name` and turning it into a variable, too. Effectively, you are trying to create a variable called `100.000000` and assign it the value of `100`.

Since the *value* of `master_volume` is `100.000000` it is illegal because you can't use `.` in a variable name.

However, if you used `SetFormat, "D", 0`, then you would force your decimals not to have any floating point (no `.000000`) and then you would be able to create a variable out of `100` or `75` or whatever the value of `master_volume` happens to be.

However, you probably *don't* want it to work that way.  You should use the simple answer proposed by alpha bravo, and just use:

```
master_volume = 100
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so well! I have removed the `%` from the `master_volume` and it is now working - _however_ it will only work one-way until I relaunch the script i.e. Press the shortcut, volume changes to 100. Press it again, nothing. Relaunch script, press shortcut, toggle to 10. Press it again ... Nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: That is a different issue.  You need to read in the docs about the "auto-execute" section.  Then, put your GUI in it's own sub with `SoundGet` as the first line of that sub (don't forget the `return` at the end!).  Then you call this sub from your hotkey.  The hotkey keeps the script in memory.  Right now your `SoundGet` sub only gets called when the script is launched - but you want it to get called when the `sub` is ran.

Comment: Perfect! I knew I was missing something! Works like a charm now, thank you so much!